# formcontrol subscribe to 2 events

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a formcontrol that I want to subscribe 2 events to.  With the code below, Only the first one gets subscribed.  How can I make them both work?

```
    this.filteredMetros = this.facCreateForm.controls['Metro'].valueChanges
          .startWith(null)
          .map(Name => Name ? this.filter(Name) : this.metros.slice());

 this.facCreateForm.controls['Metro'].valueChanges.subscribe(data=>this.onMetroChange(data));
```

Comment: You're doing something else wrong.  you can subscribe to a form controls value changes as many times as you want.

Comment: Take a look at `BehaviourSubject`. You can perform a `next(newValue)` on it on value change directly from your template. Also, if you want to 'merge' two subscriptions you should take a look at `combineLatest`.